# Why does Amazon have so much white space in its HTML?

Tags: html

If you view the source of the home page, there's somewhere around 14 newlines before the DOCTYPE. For logged-in pages in Seller Central, I'm seeing more than 400! In between components of the page, there will often be 20 newlines of padding, and sometimes much more.

To show I'm not making this up:

[image: A screenshot of Chrome's source viewer, displaying the DOCTYPE declaration on the 445th line.]

Amazon seems to be fanatical about speed, so I'm incredulous that they'd be doing this unintentionally, especially before the DOCTYPE. (Everything else could be a nicely formatted FOR loop that elects not to show some template each iteration, maybe?)

Could they be initiating a connection before the logic of the application is ready to start spitting out code, and "streams" some whitespace?

Comment: No idea, you'd have to ask them. But it could be to compensate for browser bugs. e.g. IE would not display YOUR error pages if the total size was <= 512 bytes.

Comment: That's true, but to do that for every successful page seems odd.

Comment: probably also keeps the "differently abled" away from the source. your average script kiddy would try to "hack" the page by viewing the source, and be confronted with an empty window. "zomg, amazon is magic and can hide their html!"

Comment: @MarcB: It's sad, but I've seen that.  I had to tell someone the code wasn't hidden and they just had to scroll down >.>

Comment: Could it have something to do with encoding? Specifically BOM?

Comment: @wahwahwah I'm not a character encoding expert, but if that were messed up then we'd be looking at something worse than tag soup.

Comment: Possibly something to do with server-side includes? I notice there are empty lines at different points further down the page...

Comment: So if you look at the source and compare it to the generated source they are different. The generated source gives each HTML line an id...as if it was a web page building a page in javascript or something. It's kind of crazy...anyhow depending on the page different lines are uses/not used. So you can see huge gaps between sections because those lines were not used for that page.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you contact Amazon regarding your query, as only they can provide a valid answer to your question. Below is the link to their 'Contact Us' page:

https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/contact-us/general-questions.html?skip=true

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

My guess it that they are trying to fake a "first byte" short response time.

Many web speed test (ej: http://www.webpagetest.org) value positively a fast first byte is sent to the browser, probably search engines also value this metric, since this is considered an small "processing time".

Printing some white space while the content of the page is been computed gets something to the browser fast and can reduces "first byte" times from 0.5 to 0.0 seconds.

Or maybe it is just a bug :)